# Grouping by week starting on Tuesday in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a code here where it groups all data according to their week starting day, such as Sunday, Monday, and Tuesday. Code works on Monday and Sunday but on Tuesday, as you can see, Oct 12 is grouped on Tuesday the following week.

[image: Sample grouping]

Code:

```
select case when day.week_starting = 'Sunday' then date_trunc('week', table1.date::date + 1)::date - 1
when day.week_starting = 'Tuesday' then date_trunc('week', table1.date::date + 2)::date + 1
when day.week_starting = 'Monday' then date_trunc('week', table1.date::date)::date
end as local_date_created, date
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found the workaround. Here:

```
case when day.week_starting = 'Sunday' then date_trunc('week', table1.date::date + 1)::date - 1
    when day.week_starting = 'Tuesday' then date_trunc('week', table1.date::date)::date + 1
    when day.week_starting = 'Monday' then date_trunc('week', table1.date::date)::date
    end as local_date_created,date
```